# How can I add condition in string javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My javascript code like this :

```
var res =  `<td>
                if(product.photo == photo.name)
                <div class="box-check">
                    <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                </div>
            </td>`;
```

I try like that. But seems it's wrong

How can I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

simplest (easiest) change I can think of is as follows:

```
var inner = product.photo == photo.name ? `<div class="box-check">
       <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
    </div>` : '';
var res =  `<td>${inner}</td>`;
```

alternatively

```
var res = `<td>${product.photo == photo.name?'<div class="box-check"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></div>':''}</td>`;
```

<s>but you can NOT (easily) make the `<div><span` etc multiline in this case</s>

I didn't try hard enough - nested template literals FTW :p

```
var res = `<td>${product.photo == photo.name?`<div class="box-check">
    <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
</div>`:''}</td>`;
```

Comment: *"but you can NOT (easily) make the <div><span etc multiline in this case"* - Why not? You can nest template literals inside `${...}`. Or you could say `\`<td>\` + ternary + \`</td>\`` (with or without line breaks).

Comment: I could've sworn I did try nested  templates - clearly a typo when I tried :p

Comment: @Jaromanda X, Seems you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665670/how-can-i-solve-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-identifier-in-string-javascript