# How can I solve Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in string javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My string javascript like this :

```
 <script>
 ...
     res += '<td class="${photo == photoMap[i].name ? 'success' : ''} image" id="thumb-view-'+i+'" \
                data-toggle="modal"  \
                data-target="#modal-option-'+i+'" \
                data-photo='${JSON.stringify(photoMap[i])}' \
                data-main_photo="'+photo+'" \
            > \
                <img src="/img/thumbs/'+photoMap[i].name+'" alt="${photoMap[i].alt ? photoMap[i].alt : ''}"> \
                ${photo == photoMap[i].name ? '<div class="box-check"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></div>' : ''} \
            </td>';
...
</script>
```

If the code executed, on the console exist error like this :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

It seems that the writing of the code is still not correct

If I observe, an error occurs in this section

```
res += '<td class="${photo == photoMap[i].name ? 'success' : ''} image" id="thumb-view-'+i+'" \
```

and

```
${photo == photoMap[i].name ? '<div class="box-check"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></div>' : ''} \
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: + `success` +, I think you forgot to concatenate it

Comment: @Swellar, `success` is string. No variable

Comment: Then I think the problem is you "cut" the string by using `'`, thus the compiler thought that `success` is not part of the string

Comment: They are correct.  You need to escape the quotes for success and also the empty string following it

Comment: @Swellar, So what is the right solution?

Comment: Try removing the `'` wrapping `success`

Comment: @Swellar, It's the same

Comment: @samueltoh Okay then. Try BryanEuton's suggestion

Comment: @Bryan Euton, I try like this : res += '<td class="${photo == photoMap[i].name ? \'success\' : \'\'} image" id="thumb-view-'+i+'" \. No error. But the condition not working. It to be string

Comment: @Swellar, Okay. I had try it